# how to get corresponding value in CSV through a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, csv

here is my problem, I tend to get corresponding value in CSV through a list. For example:

I have a list like

```
namelist=[1,2]
```

and csv like

```
name    id    value
 1       a     aaa
 2       b     bbb
 3       c     ccc
```

and i tend to using every element in the list to find  corresponding value in CSV. such as: 1-aaa;2-bbb. this is what i tried now：

```
with open('1.csv','rb') as f:
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for i in namelist:
    for row in reader:
        if row['name'] == namelist[i]: 
            print row['value']
```

but I got nothing. how can i fix it?
 Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

1. `csv.DictReader` reads items to a dictionary of `string:string`, not `string:int`.  So, I changed your namelist to a list of strings.  Alternatively, you could convert `row['name']` to an integer, but I figured it would be more versatile converting your namelist in this manner.
2. It would be much faster to just check `if row['name'] in namelist:` then to loop over the entire csv file for every element in namelist.

Code:

```
import csv

namelist=['1','2']
with open('1.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row['name'] in namelist: 
            print row['value']
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use indents after "with" clause. And another thing that can cause problem may be in this part of code:

```
for i in namelist:  # in that case if namelist = [1,2] i will be 1 or 2, but you need 0,1
```

Also you can try this solution if the order of the columns is always such (i mean name,id,value):

```
namelist=[1,2]

with open('1.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = list(csv.reader(f))
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(len(namelist)): # or if row[0] in namelist: 
            if row[0] == namelist[i]:
            print row[2]
```